# Relating text on multiple canvases

Tags: html, canvas

Suppose we have a few lines of question on one canvas and corresponding answers on another.Is  there a way in which if text on one canvas is chosen by mouse drag, the related text is highlighted(or struck off) on the other?? Since canvas is only a drawing object. I drew text in both using fillText, but canvas doesn't remember if it doesn't remember the co-ordinates which isn't possible as my function draws random text at different times at different co=ordinates.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to interact with your text after it's been drawn, you must "remember" that text yourself--usually by putting all the information that defines that exact text into a javascript object:

```
var question1={
    text:"What color is the sun?",
    answer:"The sun is yellow.",
    x:50,
    y:25
}
```

Then you can use that object to draw (and possible redraw) your questions and answers:

```
context1.fillText(question1.text, question1.x, question1.y);

context2.fillText(question1.answer, question1.x, question1.y);
```

If you have multiple texts, you can store them in an array:

```
var questions=[]

questions.push(question1);
```

Then you can later "remember" the information about the text:

```
var question=questions[0];

console.log("We asked: "+question.text+" at position "+x+"/"+y);
```

You can use the "remembered" information about the text to do hit-testing in your first canvas and highlighting in your second canvas.

Hit testing text is relatively straightforward.  You need to know the pixel length of the text and you can get that using the context.measureText method:

```
var textWidth = context1.measureText(question1.text).width;
```

Then you can test if the mouse is over the question by checking of the mouse is inside the bounding box of the question.

```
// assume the text-height is approximately the font-size

context1.font="14px verdana";

var textHeight=14;

if(
    mouseX>=question1.x && 
    mouseX<=question1.x+textWidth &&
    mouseY>=question1.y &&
    mouseY<=question1.y+textHeight
) {
    console.log("The mouse is over the question");
}else{
    console.log("The mouse is not over the question");
```

}

Comment: You havent't read that my canvas draws the text question at random co-ordinates. I have no way to know where it will be drawn next. I just know the co-ordinates of answer text on another canvas

Comment: At some point, your code **must know** the x,y of the random question coordinates--or else your code would not know where to draw the question!  So create your javascript object at that time when your code knows the random x,y. ;-)

Comment: I need to drag through the question to get the answer. The question and answer both being single words.

Comment: OK!!! I just saw that you are probably talking about your wordsearch puzzle you asked about in another question--I didn't realize you asked both questions!  Please see my last comment on your wordsearch question for how to highlight only correct answers.  (You don't need 2 canvases to accomplish your task--that just complicates things)  Chuckle...I guess I need another cup of coffee!